# Create installer for WPF core application

Tags: wpf, .net-core, windows-installer

I have a WPF using .net core 5, I want to create an installer with "Visual Studio Installer Projects".
I followed the usual steps and install the created installer on my machine.
The problem is when I want to run the app from the shortcut on my desktop, I get always this error message :

[image: Error Message Box]

The message box will close and nothing happen whether I click 'yes' or 'no'.

Any idea what can cause this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019#prerequisites-for-net-core-31). In your case the correct .NET Version.

> If you would like your installer to be able to install the necessary runtime for a framework-dependent .NET Core 3.1 app, you can do this using prerequisites. From the properties dialog of your installer project, open the Prerequisites... dialog and you'll see the following entries:

> The .NET Core Runtime... option should be selected for console applications, .NET Desktop Runtime... should be selected for WPF/WinForms applications.

Comment: Thank you for your help,i have already set the prerequisites to .net desktop runtime 5.0.6. but still the same error, one thing is this trials are on my developement machine, which has already the .net installed. normally it should start without issue, but still i have this error ?